# How to echo my HTML in PHP and get rid of an error message?

Tags: php, html, echo, quotations

I'm trying to loop through an array and pass the values into HTML. My loop echos a large block of code. This is a small portion of the code I'm struggling with.

```
<p class='gl-item-title'>'.$array['title']'</p>
<p class='gl-item-category'>'.$array['type']'</p>
```

I get this error message

Parse error:

> syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),     expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)    in C:\MAMP\htdocs\simsestate\Sims-esate\index.php on line 223

I don't understand this error. Would somebody give tips on how to echo big chunks of HTML in PHP?

Comment: Seems like you're missing a catenation operator `.` after the `$array[*]` bits.

Comment: Seems like you're missing a lot from these two lines of code...

Comment: Show where the php starts and ends

Comment: I suggest you read through a php tutorial. The first lesson should cover this particular problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p class='gl-item-title'>'.$array['title'].'</p>
<p class='gl-item-category'>'.$array['type'].'</p>
```

When you join strings you have to use dot,
I don't know how rest of your code looks like but in this part you forgot dot after array index variable

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes `"` or escaped single quotes `\'` for your HTML, additionally you miss a `.` after `$array['']` variables

```
echo '<p class="gl-item-title">'.$array['title'].'</p>';
echo '<p class="gl-item-category">'.$array['type'].'</p>';
```

The above can be written also like this:

```
<p class="gl-item-title"><?php echo $array['title']; ?></p>
<p class="gl-item-category"><?php echo $array['type']; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need another dot after the variable. Try this:

```
echo '<p class=\'gl-item-title\'>'.$array['title'].'</p>';
```